# Find first occurrence of character in file in C?

Tags: c, file

This can be done in a string, with `strrchr()`, but what about finding the first occurrence of a string in a file? So I can know how much to read from the file? Is there a direct way to do that, or will I just have to get all the contents of the file as a string and then use `strrchr()`?

Comment: *"I just have to get all the contents of the file as a string and then use strrchr()"* this will give you still last occurance?

Comment: Why would you use `strrchr()` for finding the *first* occurance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file contents and use `strrchr()` on the data you read.

But you don't have to read the whole file at once. You can read chunk by chunk and scan each chunk with `strrchr()` until you found the character.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it!